# Проблема с логикой вывода данных

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, появилась проблема с логикой вывода данных на страницу. 
Нужно чтобы определенные записи с БД выводились на странице в определенной "категории". Я попытался этого добиться следующим образом: 
Присвоил каждой записи ID категории, к которой она относится и if'ом проверял, вышел следующий код:

```
<?php 
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_response) ):
    $is_stock = isStock($row['stock'])
?> 
<h3 class="page-header">
    PKVZ
</h3>
<?php 
if($row['social'] == 1){
    echo showGoods($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['price'], $row['quanity'], $row['stock'], $is_stock);
    continue;
}
?>

<h3 class="page-header">
    Riston
</h3>

<?php 
if($row['social'] == 2){
    echo showGoods($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['price'], $row['quanity'], $row['stock'], $is_stock);
    continue;
}
?>

<h3 class="page-header">
    Labby
</h3>
<?php 
    if($row['social'] == 3){
        echo showGoods($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['price'], $row['quanity'], $row['stock'], $is_stock);
        continue;
    }
?>

<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Но вот появилась **проблема**: 
В while() попадает и HTML, поэтому на выводе мы имеем, например, при двух записях:

Категория №1
[Запись с БД]
Категория №2
[Запись с БД]
Категория №3
Категория №1
Категория №2
Категория №3

Т.е. HTML также входит в цикл, а это вовсе не надо. 
По-сути, задача детская, но что-то не могу допереть, как сделать. С foreach тоже не выходит.

Собственно, сам вопрос: как вывести данные с БД, чтобы определенные данные были в определенном месте в HTML, учитывая что данных больше 1 записи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

короче, вам надо так:

```
- категория 1
- запись
- запись
- категория 2
- запись
- запись
- запись
...
```

Верно понял?

1. если совсем по-феншую, то заведите в базе таблицу с категориями **(cat_id, cat_name)**, и названия категорий храните в базе... одна категория - одна запись.
   После этого, к вашим данным в запросе добавьте эту таблицу категорий
   (к селекту добавляем **cat_table.cat_name**, а к FROM - **inner join cat_table ct on ct.cat_id = your_table_alias.social** (я правильно понял, что social - это тот самый id категории, верно?
2. отсортируйте данные в запросе (добавьте в ваш запрос **order by your_table_alias.social**, если по id сортироваться)
3. вывод данных... тут че-то у вас вообще каша... зачем вам три одинаковых блока вывода под разными условиями??

   ```
   $current_cat = null;
   while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_response) ) {
       $is_stock = isStock($row['stock']);
       if($current_cat !== $row['social']) {
           echo '<h3 class="page-header">'.$row['cat_name'].'</h3>';
           $current_cat = $row['social'];
       }
       echo showGoods($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['price'], $row['quanity'], $row['stock'], $is_stock);
   }
   ```

ну а если совсем лень заводить новую таблицу (пропускаем шаг 1), то

```
echo '<h3 class="page-header">'.$row['cat_name'].'</h3>';
```

меняем на

```
switch($row['social']) {
    case 1: echo '<h3 class="page-header">Название категории первой</h3>'; break;
    case 2: echo '<h3 class="page-header">Второй категории название</h3>'; break;
    case 3: echo '<h3 class="page-header">Третья категория</h3>'; break;
    default: echo '<h3 class="page-header">Неведомая категория</h3>'; break;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за расширенный ответ. Да, чутка лень, но хочу разобраться с первым вариантом, ибо в будущем, возможно, очень даже пригодиться. Надеюсь, Вы не против ответить на вопросы в динамике работы. Честно говоря, не особо разобрался с запросом - пока что-то такое выходит: http://i.imgur.com/rpFUtx3.jpg. Хочу почитать синтаксисе подобных запросов, не подскажите ссылку? 

Пока вопрос:

Comment: по ссылке - всё не так... вообще :)

Comment: да я уже понял. Хочу в синтаксисе разобраться, поэтому интересуюсь, дабы лишний раз Вас по глупым вопросам не дергать.

Comment: ну, тут гугл в руки :)
https://www.google.ru/search?q=sql+select+inner+join+примеры